# Haskell - Convert between matrix types

Tags: haskell, matrix

I am using the `Numeric.LinearAlgebra` library. This is my code:

```
customConv :: Matrix Z
customConv = conv2 ((3><3)[1..]) ((1><1)[1.1])
```

My problem is that I want that the output will be from type `Matrix Z`.

Now the type is not `Z` because the conv is with 1.1

Is there any function to round all the values of the matrix and make it from this type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on how you want to round the values.
If you want to round to the nearest integer, then you can use `cmap round`:

```
λ> cmap round $ conv2 ((3><3)[1..]) ((1><1)[1.1 :: R]) :: Matrix Z
(3><3)
 [ 1, 2,  3
 , 4, 6,  7
 , 8, 9, 10 ]
```

`cmap` has the following signature:

```
cmap :: (Element b, Container c e) => (e -> b) -> c e -> c b
```

Which means it's like `fmap` only constrained to types that can be held by hmatrix containers.

If, instead, you want to crop the decimals, you can use `toZ`:

```
λ> toZ $ conv2 ((3><3)[1..]) ((1><1)[1.1 :: R]) :: Matrix Z
(3><3)
 [ 1, 2, 3
 , 4, 5, 6
 , 7, 8, 9 ]
```

`toZ` has the following signature:

```
toZ :: Container c e => c e -> c Z
```

Which means it will convert anything to a container of `Z`. It does so by cropping the decimals.